# Как распознать url в qr-code android?

Tags: android, qr

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой. Уже пару часов сижу думаю никак, не могу разобраться. Мне нужно подключить к моему приложению сканер qr-кода а именно чтоб распознавал не только текст что закодирован в qr-коде но и ссылки если они присутствуют. То есть если человек сканирует картинку с qr-кодом и там оказывается ссылка то приложение откроет браузер с этой ссылкой. Помогите пожалуйста это реализовать или скиньте какой то пример нормальный. Для считывания текста использовал библиотеку ZXing core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача сводится не к распознанию ссылок в qr-коде, а к извлечению ссылок из распознанного текста. Ссылки можно извлеч из строки на пример вот так:

```
ArrayList retrieveLinks(String text) {
    ArrayList links = new ArrayList();
    Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find()) {
        String urlStr = m.group();
        char[] stringArray1 = urlStr.toCharArray();

        if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")"))
        {

            char[] stringArray = urlStr.toCharArray();

            char[] newArray = new char[stringArray.length-2];
            System.arraycopy(stringArray, 1, newArray, 0, stringArray.length-2);
            urlStr = new String(newArray);
            System.out.println("Finally Url ="+newArray.toString());

        }
        System.out.println("...Url..."+urlStr);
        links.add(urlStr);
    }
    return links;
}
```

То есть на входе - распознанная строка, на выходе - массив из ссылок, которые в ней содержатся

**UPD**
[[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf) дополнил (см. его комментарий), за что ему спасибо!

Comment: Вот только на интернационализированных URL эта регулярка не сработает. Да и на локальных доменах выдаст ложное срабатывание. Так что не следует изобретать велосипед и стоит использовать [`Patterns.WEB_URL`][1], почти полностью покрывающий RFC 3987.

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#WEB_URL

Comment: @falstaf нашел ответ на stackoverflow...    
Я правильно понимаю, что достаточно заменить строчку    
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);    
на строчку    
 Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;

??

Comment: Да, так. И кстати, а что у вас там за магия с удалением скобок, это зачем?

Comment: А если в qr-коде закодирована ссылка на play market? То как её считывать?